# Book for software design

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I am trying to find a book which contains information and best practices in software development and design. More specifically I need a book which talks about how each layer talks to other layers, for example how the logic layer of the server talks to the data access layer and vise versa, or what information should the client application send to the server and how to do this.

Mainly I would like it to be for Java development but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Head First Software Development and Head First Design Patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) by Martin Fowler

Answer (score 0):

[Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

written by Steve McConnell. I think it will be helpful.